# Why the running time of a loop is n - i - 1?

Tags: runtime

Why the running time of the loop from the following code fragment is `n-i-1` and not `n-1`. `n` is the number of elements in the array `A`

```
small = i;
for(j = i+1 ; j < n; j++)
    if(A[j] < A[small])
       small = j;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a math question more than anything. You start off your loop by initializing j as i+1. You then run until j = n. As j increments by 1, there will be n-j --> n-(i+1) --> n-i-1 runs.